# how to calculate parameters in convolution layers

Tags: conv-neural-network

Suppose we have a 10x10x3 color image input and we want to stack two convolutional layers with kernel size 3x3 with 10 and 20 filters respectively. How many parameters do we have to train for these two layers including bias?

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: padding = "same" (i.e. input dimension to each layer = output dimension from that layer)

Input image height and width do not affect the parameter size.

Conv_layer_1 = (kernal_size * color_channels + 1)*filters = (3*3*3 + 1)*10 = 280

Conv_layer_2* = (kernal_size * prev_filters + 1)*filters = (3*3*10 + 1)*20 = 1820

*and all future Conv layers

Trainable params: 280 + 1820 = 2100

See [this blog post](https://medium.com/@iamvarman/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-in-the-cnn-5bd55364d7ca) for more detail.

Comment: @MoRebaie you're welcome. Please accept the answer by clicking the tick beside it.